# Does the "Riccati LMI" implies boundedness?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, control-theory, linear-matrix-inequality

Assume a matrix $P\succeq0$ satisfies the "Riccati LMI"
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
FPF^T - P + M & FPH^T + S\\
HPF^T+S^T& HPH^T + I
\end{pmatrix}\succeq0
\end{align}
with $M\succ0$ and arbitrary $S$. Is the matrix $P$ has to be bounded when the pair $(F,H)$ is detectable?

**Detectability def.**: There exists a matrix K s.t. $\rho(F-KH)<1$ ($\rho$ is the spectral radius).
An alternative (simpler?) formulation is that for all eigenvectors $Fv=\lambda v$ with $|\lambda|\ge1$, $Hv\neq0$.

**Detectability is necessary**:
Choose $F=2,H=0,S=0,M=1$, then the LMI is
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
P + 1 & 0\\
0& 1
\end{pmatrix}\succeq0,
\end{align}
and is satisfied with arbitrarily large $P$.

Comment: When  $M > 0,$ the comment by @user1551 still applies, except that $F$ somewhat smaller than $\sqrt{2}$ is sufficient to exhibit the unboundedness of $P$.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Can you pls explain, the Schur complement of the matrices sum is $P(1-P)$ and its positivity implies $0\le P\le1$.

Comment: I misread the off-diagonal, so withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is true, even without assuming $M,P\succeq0$.  I do, however, need that $\rho(P)=\|P\|_2$; this is true as long as you mean "finite-dimensional matrix" when you say "matrix", but fails for operators in general.

For simplicity of notation, let $$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&-K\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}M&S\\S^{\mathsf{T}}&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-K^{\mathsf{T}}\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$J=F-KH\text{;}$$ we know $\rho(J)<1$.  Also, let $r(P)=\sup_{\|w\|\leq1}{w^{\mathsf{T}}Pw}$ denote the [numerical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Numerical_range&oldid=1033714206) of $P$; by property 13 in the link, $r(P)$ is unbounded iff $P$ is.

Testing the Riccati LMI against $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-K^{\mathsf{T}}\end{bmatrix}v$ and rearranging, we have \begin{align*}
v^{\mathsf{T}}Pv-v^{\mathsf{T}}Bv&\leq v^{\mathsf{T}}(F-KH)P(F-KH)^{\mathsf{T}}v \\
&=v^{\mathsf{T}}JPJ^{\mathsf{T}}v \\
&\leq r(P)\rho(J)^2\|v\|^2\tag{1}
\end{align*}  Inequality (1) is the only step in this proof that requires $\rho(P)=\|P\|_2$.

Now take a sequence of unit vectors $\{v_n\}_n$ such that $v_n^{\mathsf{T}}Pv_n\to r(P)$; by passing to a subsequence, we may also assume that $v_n^{\mathsf{T}}Bv_n\to c$ (for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$).  Taking limits in (1) and rearranging, $$r(P)(1-\rho(J)^2)\leq c$$  This bounds $r(P)$.

(This proof also shows a little more once you assume $P\not\preceq0$.  Since $r(P)\geq0$, we must have $c\geq0$, which implies that $B$ is not negative semidefinite either.  One should then have $S$ "smaller" than $M$…but that's another question.)

Comment: @Morad: Yes; my original post was in error.  I've replaced it with a correct argument now.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! The constant $c$ can be negative, right? did you use $P\succeq0$? I would also add at the beginning of the answer that this is a proof and not a counterexample.

Comment: @Morad: Yes, I think $c$ can be negative; just take $K=S=1$, $M=0$.

Comment: @Morad: No, I did not use $P\succeq0$.  My first draft of the solution used that condition (plus self-adjointness), but it turned out to be unnecessary.

Comment: @JacobManaker: Very nice proof.

Comment: @Morad: If $c<0$, then $P$ must be negative definite. Here what is called the numerical range is just the maximum eigenvalue since $P$ is symmetric. Note that if $B\succ0$, then $c>0$ automatically. A sufficient condition for that is that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} M & S\\S^T & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite

Comment: @KBS: Since we are working over the reals, positive operators need not be symmetric (nor have real eigenvalues that can be ordered for a maximum).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Positive_operator_(Hilbert_space)&oldid=1066786265#On_HC,_if_A_%E2%89%A5_0_then_A_is_symmetric) gives an example.  (Your analysis of $c$ is correct, though.)

Comment: Thanks again. Would be nice if you add to your answer a comment on the necessary assumptions in your proof. For instance, you do not need $M\succ0$ but $P\succeq0$ is necessary.

Comment: @JacobManaker Yes, you are right in general but here we are in finite dimensions (the OP mentions that $P$ is a matrix). In such a case, $P\succeq0$ implicitly means that $P$ is symmetric positive semidefinite.

Comment: @Morad: OK, I've added a remark on assumptions.

Comment: @KBS: If $P\succeq0$ in finite dimensions means not just positive semidefinite, but also symmetric, (and Morad intends to restrict to the finite-dimensional case — I know there are some physicists and engineers that describe operators as "infinite matrices") then yes, your analysis is correct in all ways.

Comment: @JacobManaker In any way, it is nice to see that the proof works in quite a general setting. It would be interesting to know the origin of the problem. It looks like a dissipativity condition for a linear discrete-time system with the difference that the inequality sign of the LMI is reversed.

Comment: Why is $v^{\mathsf{T}}JPJ^{\mathsf{T}}v\leq r(P)\rho(J)^2\|v\|^2$? E.g. when $P=I$ and $v$ is a unit vector, the LHS is $\|J^\top v\|^2$, whose maximum attainable value is $\|J\|_2^2$, but the RHS is $\rho(J)^2$, which in general is strictly less than $\|J\|_2^2$ (unless all largest-sized eigenvalues of $J$ are semisimple).

Comment: @user1551: Yikes!  When I concocted this answer, I relied on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Matrix_norm&oldid=1069529924), which said $\rho(J)=\|J\|_2$.  I've edited it so that warns that these are not the same in infinite dimensions.  All right, this answer doesn't work in infinite dimensions; I'll add a remark.

Comment: This equality already fails in finite dimension, as argued in my previous comment. I don't see in anywhere the Wikipedia entry you mentioned has stated that $\rho(J)=\|J\|_2$. I also don't understand your edit. The equality $\rho(P)=\|P\|_2$ (which is true because $P$ is Hermitian) doesn't justify that $\rho(J)=\|J\|_2$ (which is false in general).

Comment: @Morad Sorry, I have no idea how to prove or disprove the statement. And no, all I can say for now is that $v^TPv-v^TJPJ^Tv\le v^TBv$ for all $v$. Since $r(P)$ and $r(JPJ^T)$ may be attained by different $v$s, I don't see how one can immediately conclude that $r(P)-r(JPJ^T)\le c$.

Comment: @JacobManaker Can you please respond to his comment? it seems to me that this proof is currently invalid.

Comment: @Morad: I continue to think my argument proves the inequality in finite dimensions.  My proof is pretty sharp, so if user1551 has a counterexample to a step in my proof, then that should be straightforward to bootstrap into a counterexample to your original question.  And such a counterexample should probably get posted that as an answer (so I can upvote it!).

Comment: @user1551 explained that $J$ is not symmetric and therefore $\rho(J)\neq\|J\|_2$.